# Java Spring Boot - Unauthorized, Postman

Tags: java, spring, maven, oauth-2.0, postman

I ran my Spring application after following that tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOgCMtYMr2Q&list=PLcoE64orFoVsxAam_BuQBrNC8IO238SwH&index=2
Everything is working but... when I try to do POST request

`localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user&password=password` Postman gives me that issue:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-06-27T13:46:33.144+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/oauth/token"
}
```

One of the comments could be an answer
"Rocketman did not say (or maybe I missed it) that you need to specify basic auth, client id and secret. Once that was done, then I was able to obtain the access token."
But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Actually, you need to set the username and password in the blogApplication.java, then try to hit the OAuth URL it will give the access token. Which you need to pass in header key as Authorization and value as bearer accessToken. It will work

Comment: WWW-Authenticate →Bearer realm="oauth2-resource", error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify basic authentication, client id and secret password. In this case the client id is **my-trusted-client** and the password is **secret**. Below is the full code which is used to get the toke:

```
    login(){
            var params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.append('grant_type', 'password');
            params.append('username', this.username);
            params.append('password',this.password);
            axios({
                method:'post',
                url:'oauth/token',
                auth:{username:'my-trusted-client',password:'secret'},
                headers: {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"},
                data:params
            }).then(function(response){
                set_cookie("access_token",response.data.access_token);
                document.location.replace("/");
            });
        }
```